# CSS styles using getElementsByTagName not taking effect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add an event listener to inputs in a modal such that when the inputs are selected (focus event fired), the height and overflow attributes of the body are changed.

I'm using getElementsByTagName to get an array of all the inputs in the modal, and then using a for loop to add the listener to all of them. I know these listeners are being properly attached because as I select the different inputs, the console.log statement fires.

Curiously, the console.log statement prints out "100%", but if I copy and paste that command into the actual console, it returns an empty string.

Neither the height nor the overflow attributes of the body are changed when I inspect them, before or after I focus on an input. But, if I copy those style declarations into the console they immediately take effect, and then document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style'][*attribute*] returns either 100% or 'hidden' in accordance with whichever attribute I fill in.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

    for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
        inputs[i].addEventListener('focus', function(){
            document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['height'] = '100%';
            document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['overflow'] = 'hidden';

            console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['height'])
        })
    }
```

Since my commands work when copy/pasted into the console, I am confident that there are no spelling or syntax errors. The weirdest part is that when I select the inputs, the console.log statement that I expect fires, but without any of the effects actually taking place. I have a feeling this is some sort of scoping issue, but I'm not sure why my js isn't doing what I expect it to.

Edit: After doing some more testing, I realized that duh, my modal is an iframe so the body tag that I am selecting is the body of the modal and not of the greater outer page.

This is curious, because I would think that since there are two bodies on the page, running document.getElementsByTagName('body') would return an array instead of just the first body it encounters.

So I think at this point, the question becomes "how do I select the body on the outside of an iframe/modal?"

Comment: Try using `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.height = '100%';`, etc.

Comment: Is your code located at the bottom of the body? If it's in the head (or somewhere weird) it's likely your javascript is executing before the elements even exist.

Comment: Are you sure the DOM is ready when your script runs? Try to trigger your code on `window.onload`.

Comment: @PeterB `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.height` and `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['height']` are functionally identical. I'd even prefer OP's way to get the property because you can also access properties named with two words divided by a dash without naming them differently, e.g. `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['background-color']` as opposed to the 'quirky' camel case rewrite `document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor`.

Comment: @peterB I have tried this, and the same behavior happens, as can be seen here http://i.imgur.com/o8dTP9x.png. The (4) 100% were me clicking back and forth between some inputs, but then you can see on the next line that the actual style of the attr hasn't take effect until I enter it in manually into the command line.

Comment: @DrewKennedy the code is in a script tag at the bottom of the page

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but instead of a loop, why don't you use event bubbling and capturing?

Comment: @connexo

This may be a possibility, though shouldn't the listener fire every time I click the input, so as long as the DOM elements load eventually it should work. Also I'm attempting this on the body, so I wouldn't even be able to click the inputs if the body el was not rendered.

Nevertheless, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: @Hopper so like adding the listener to the topmost element in the modal, since the events in the nested elements will bubble up to the top?

Comment: yes, this frees up the code from unnecessary identical addEventListeners

Comment: @connexo I implemented the following code http://i.imgur.com/Btrna91.png and the same exact behavior is occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the root cause of my problem was that the modal in which I was applying my event listeners was an iframe, and so had it's own body tag. Because of this, the attributes I was trying to apply to the greater body that contained the modal were not taking effect and were being assigned to the body of the iframe instead.

To get around this, all I needed to do was change my attribute declarations to

```
parent.document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['height'] = '100%';;
parent.document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0]['style']['overflow'] = 'hidden';
```

In the iframe, window.parent refers to the global object of the parent document, not the document object itself.